Looking for an 80's-90's era movie with an evil (robot?) child
I can only remember this movie faintly, so I might get some details wrong.
First off, it might be a movie made in Poland, I remember the language spoken being Polish. I remember the sound effects definitely having that 80's vibe to them. I believe it had a group of children, and also an older man, possibly a professor or a scientist of some sort, leading them through whatever it was he was leading them through. I'm thinking scientist, as I remember some sort of machinery in the movie, though I don't remember what kind. 
The thing that stands out to me the most was the evil-looking kid, as mentioned in the title. Possibly an android? I remember he was pretty emotionless, rebellious too. I think he fired lasers? Not sure on that one.

It might be "Akademia Pana Kleksa (1983)", I think it would be something around "Mr. Kleks (inkblot) Academy" in English. or one of related movies (based on children book).
It is Polish, there is professor (Kleks) leading bunch of children through adventures in Never Ending Story style. And one robo-kid made by pair of pesky scientists which goes crazy on rampage. I do not recall any lasers, but there it had bunch of scenes with epilepsy inducing old-school special effects. 
And apparently professor knew Tony ;)

